# Pinning Shortcuts to the Taskbar by Batch

Tags: batch, taskbar, pinning

I'm trying to pin shortcuts to the taskbar with batch.
The method I am using is taking a pre-made shortcut from a Setup program, and copying it to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`.
When I restart Windows 7 (or `explorer.exe`), there is no effect.
The exact code I am using is:

```
move "*.lnk" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"
```

Also, a question: Can I replace the shortcut file with a Straight-up `.EXE`?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @gronostaj Windows 7 x86

Answer (score 0):

The reason simple file copy fails is because the Windows she is involved.

Use vbscript or powershell or get this guys script from CodeProject.com
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win

He provide the original Microsoft Source documentation, which applies almost 99% of the time.

Below are some references for the Windows Shell Environment Variables, which help in shell operations from scripts.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4941-shell-command.html

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx
http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/244817-registry-differences-between-shell-folders-user-shell-folders.html
https://github.com/libyal/libfwsi/wiki/Shell-Folder-identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The reason simple file copy fails is because the Windows she is involved.

Use vbscript or powershell or get this guys script from CodeProject.com
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win

He provide the original Microsoft Source documentation, which applies almost 99% of the time.

Below are some references for the Windows Shell Environment Variables, which help in shell operations from scripts.
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4941-shell-command.html